# Dojo build with xstyle, issue with Font Awasome with ASCII conversion

Tags: css, dojo, ascii, dojo-build

I am using [xstyle](https://github.com/kriszyp/xstyle) plugin into my dojo build process.

All css is concatenated and minified, but I have notice that it translate ASCII reference like this

```
#test {
  content:  "\f000"
}
```

to this:

```
#test {
  content: "";
}
```

I need instead to keep the same ASCII value as `content:  "\f000"` in the final CSS style.

In my specific case I am building a dojo flat theme  which include [Font Awasome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

How to achieve this?

Comment: I feel your pain. Not a lot of info or even decent info out there on the Dojo build process. Just a lot of smashing one's head against the wall.